# In chrome (or any browser) can you see just the diff in css styles as you add and remove classes?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I have the following css

```
.unfocus {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: .3;
}

.focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there a way to view just the properties that changed on an element as I replace the .unfocus class with .focus?

Comment: No, you'd need a 3rd party add-on for that.

Comment: are the classes being switched depending on when the element is focussed on? guessing it's an input?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension of google chrome store that can achieve this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-diff/pefnhibkhcfooofgmgoipfpcojnhhljm

See the video demonstration:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSQM-VwCj6E

You can see differences of:

- Element's different state (focus/ unfocus)
- Compare css differences between tabs
- Compare elements with other elements

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're toggling these classes based on whether an input element is focussed on?

The closest feature to this would be within the toggle element state menu in Chrome devtools. The button is titled `:hov`.

Clicking this will show you 4 toggle options. If you choose `:focus` it will display any changes in the CSS properties below.

[image]